# Android DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode() not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I have a Navigation Drawer (**appcompat v7**) in my app which is working perfectly fine.

Now I want to disable it, until the user buys an in-app-purchase to unlock additional functionality. So in my `Activity.onCreate()`, after initializing the drawer and populating it, I am calling this function:

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

This function is not doing anything. The drawer continues to open and close as normal after tapping the drawer carat in the actionbar. I tried calling this function in `Activity.onResume()` without any difference.

What is the correct way to use this function? 
(I tried looking online for answers, but couldn't find anything which addresses my issue). Any help is appreciated, as I am stuck on this issue for quite sometime now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);`

is only disabling the opening drawer layout by swiping  till you click navigation drawer icon
 keep a boolean variable

write `mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);` in `onStart()` and also write below lines of code

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

        if(!disabled)
        {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerLinearLayout)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerLinearLayout);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerLinearLayout);
            }
        }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

this will work for sure

Comment: `onOptionsItemSelected` is called  when an item from the Overflow menu is selected, not when an item from the Navigation Drawer is selected.

Comment: Thats why i wrote item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home
it is aslo called when home button on navigation drawer clicked

Comment: @SHASHIDHARMANCHUKONDA help me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895568/how-to-lock-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 3):

When you call `setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)` it locks opening and closing drawer **only** by swipes.

The drawer continues to open and close as normal after tapping the drawer carat in the action bar because  your drawer will still respond to calls to `openDrawer(int)`, `closeDrawer(int)` although a drawer is locked.
You need to add some logic in your action bar menu button listener and not to call openDrawer(int) when you don't want it to open.

Btw, it is okay to call `setDrawerLockMode(int)` in `onСreate`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with DrawerLayout and used gravity. I have reported it here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738274