# setDrawerLockMode not working in android?

Tags: android, swipe, drawerlayout

I want to lock swipe left-right and right-left of DrawerLayout.

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
```

onCreate:

```
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_OPEN);
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Click button to open drawerLayout:

```
drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
```

and close:

```
drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
```

I try setDrawerLockMode in onCreate, onResume, onStart but not working, it still can open, close by swipe it.

**Edit 2:**

It work with:

`android:layout_gravity="start"`

and not work with:

```
android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
```

Any helps. Thanks.

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074106/android-drawerlayout-setdrawerlockmode-not-working

Comment: I see this not fix my case, the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413116/why-i-cant-lock-drawerlayout-with-layout-gravity . But no one can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Add gravity value too when using setDrawerLockMode();

Do this :

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, GravityCompat.END);
```

This should work